# Potential Energy of long chain resting on quarter circle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity

[image]

Here I am trying to calculate gravitational potential Energy of chain so that by conservation of kinetic and potential energy i can calculate velocity
I am considering small element dm and it's potential energy dP

[image]

I can't move forward I need help

Comment: By "chain" do you mean something like a homogeneous density string/rope/bar or do you really mean a chain made up of many links? In the limit where the size of the chain links is much smaller than the dimensions of the circle, these would be the same, but in the opposite limit it could become complicated.

Comment: I don't quite understand your last equation,  but wouldn't you just have to find the center of mass?

Answer (score 2):

Finding the gravitational potential energy is equivalent to finding the center of mass of the chain.

For an object of density $D(\mathbf{r})$ and total mass $M$ the coordinates of the center of mass are given by

$$\mathbf{R}_\mathrm{COM}=\frac{1}{M}\int D(\mathbf{r}) \mathbf{r}~dV$$

In cylindrical coordinates, $dV=\rho~d\rho~d\phi~dz$ the integral becomes

$$\mathbf{R}_\mathrm{COM}=\frac{1}{M}\int D \begin{pmatrix}\rho\cos\phi\\ \rho\sin\phi\\z\end{pmatrix} \rho ~d\rho~d\phi~dz$$

Now, $D~d\rho~dz=D_\mathrm{lin}=M/(\pi r/2)=2M/(\pi r)$ is the line density of the chain. Here a homogeneous density has been assumed. Leaving out the trivial third coordinate, and putting the quarter-circle in the fourth quadrant, the center of mass coordinate becomes:

$$\mathbf{R}_\mathrm{COM}=\frac{2r}{\pi} \int_{\frac{3\pi}{2}}^{2\pi}\begin{pmatrix}\cos\phi\\ \sin\phi\end{pmatrix} d\phi\\
=\frac{2r}{\pi}\begin{pmatrix}1\\ -1\end{pmatrix}$$

Thus the center of mass is located a distance of $r-\frac{2r}{\pi}$ above the surface and the potential energy becomes:
$$U=Mgr\left(1-\frac{2}{\pi}\right)$$

Equating this with the kinetic energy, $Mv^2/2$ gives a velocity of 
$$v=\sqrt {2gr\left(1-\frac{2}{\pi}\right)}$$

Comment: Thanks. You tried to answer rather than questioning as others

Answer (score 1):

Instead of taking linear elements take angular elements. Like a d(theta) element at theta angle. And then u will be able to solve it easily.[image]

Comment: Thanks. You tried to answer rather than questioning as others and also given the exact solution i needed